# Calling a button from a second xml file from the main .java file

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a text adventure game in android studio using buttons to progress through the map. I'm trying to call a button that is in the second page of the game. I know the problem is that it can't find the button since its on the second page and the page the .java file is looking at is page one. Is there a way to have the .java file look at all .xml page at the same time?

```
public class textAdven extends AppCompatActivity {

boolean male;
int gender;
private Button boyButt;
private Button girlButt;
private TextView genderBox1;
private Button shedButt, fieldButt, yardButt, lookAround1, cabButt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_adven);

    boyButt =(Button) findViewById(R.id.boyButt);
    girlButt =(Button) findViewById(R.id.girlButt);
    shedButt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.shedButt);
    cabButt =(Button) findViewById(R.id.cabButt);
    lookAround1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.lookAround1);
    fieldButt=(Button) findViewById(R.id.fieldButt);
    yardButt  =(Button) findViewById(R.id.yardButt);

    boyButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.adven2);
            male = true;
            genderBox1 = findViewById(R.id.genderBox1);
            genderBox1.setText("boy");

        }
    });

    girlButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.adven2);
            male = false;
            genderBox1 = findViewById(R.id.genderBox1);
            genderBox1.setText("girl");
        }
    });

    shedButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.adven3);
        }
    });

    yardButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.adven2);
        }
    });



}


}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with i have to look other button, isn't possible navigate to that activity and press the button? or do the thing that you have to do without pressing it?

Comment: I added the code there. I mean that when I go into that part of the app, when the .java file is ran basically, the app crashes and tells me that it cant find "shedButt" because its not in activity_text_adven

Comment: Of course it say that, because is from another activity, to set the click listener the button has to be in the layout, so you should change the activity by using an intent, and set the click listener in that activity instead using just one

Comment: Is there no way of doing in all in .java file? I want to be able to track variables in 1 file

Comment: You could do it by show/hide the buttons that you don't use, and when you click 1, button 2 appear, but i should see better how games is structured to give more advice.

How should appear the game?

How are buttons?

Comment: If you need to bind the click listener in the same class, you most likely need it in the same layout file. Otherwise, you should look into fragments and make your Activity the manager of all the logic.

Comment: My plan is to have different .xml files for the different areas in the game. The buttons will appear on the screen that way. I don't think showing and hiding them will be good as it'll just get confusing if I'm gonna have like 10 levels all in one .xml file.